# update the state of the button by getting a boolean value from firebase realtime database in Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, switch-statement

I am trying to control my switch by getting value from firebase realtime database. Its listening to the boolean value whenever it is changed but i dont understand how to use that value to toggle the button when the value in realtime database changed. This is basically an app in which you can control the switch via app and app via hardware with realtime database firebase as a bridge between them.

Here is my `main.dart` file:

```
import 'package:firebaseiot/screens/iotscreen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        'iotscreen/': (BuildContext context) => IotScreen()
      },
      title: "Firebase IOT",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme:
          ThemeData(
            brightness: Brightness.dark,
            backgroundColor: Colors.black
            ),
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      home: IotScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my `iotscreen.dart` file:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class IotScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _IotScreenState createState() => _IotScreenState();
}

class _IotScreenState extends State<IotScreen> {
  @override
  final DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  bool state = false;
  bool newValue;

  onUpdate() {
    setState(() {
      state = !state;
    });
  }

  void getStatus() async {
    String newValue = (await DatabaseReference.child("LightState/switch").once()).value;
    print(newValue);
    print(state);
    setState(() {
      if (newValue == 'TRUE' || newValue == 'true') {
        state = true;
      } else if(newValue == 'FALSE' || newValue == 'false') {
        state = false;
      }
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
        [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
          //stream: DatabaseReference.child("LightState").onValue,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData &&
                !snapshot.hasError &&
                snapshot.data.snapshot.value != null) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    child: SafeArea(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Icon(
                            Icons.clear_all,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "MY ROOM",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          Icon(Icons.settings)
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              "Temperature",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              "30", // test data
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "Humidity",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "80", // test data
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 80),
                  FloatingActionButton.extended(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      onUpdate();
                      onWrite();
                      await getStatus();
                      print(state);
                    },
                    label: state ? Text("ON") : Text("OFF"),
                    elevation: 20,
                    backgroundColor: state ? Colors.yellow : Colors.white,
                    icon: state
                        ? Icon(Icons.visibility)
                        : Icon(Icons.visibility_off),
                  )
                ],
              );
            } else
              return Container();
          },
          stream: DatabaseReference.child("LightState").onValue),
    );
  }

  Future<void> onWrite() async {
    DatabaseReference.child("LightState").set({"switch": !state});
  }
}
```

And here is my .json file:

```
{
  "LightState" : {
    "switch" : true
  }
}
```

Please help me in using the value listened to toggle the button when the value in the realtime database changed from 'false' to 'true'. I use this flutter library `'firebase_database: ^7.1.1'` (https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_database)

Comment: You need to create a model of your document in the stream builder then update the switch state according to the change.

Comment: Hi @Furkan, thank you for your advice. I'm a newbie in Flutter so I still don't get it. Could you show me how to do that? By the way, thanks a lot. Have a nice day.